# REST NodeJs Framework. (Дайте совет)

Tags: javascript, node.js, framework, rest

Нужен совет - какой выбрать фреймворк для ноды. Есть условия - REST + авторизация + большое сообщество + хорошая документация.

Какой сейчас самый популярный?

Answer (score 1):

Я посматриваю на hapi.js , вроде всё вышеперечисленное есть, хотя честно скажу в деле не пробовал пока-что, но в целом очень позитивное впечатление от документации и размера

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/)
авторизация, REST плагинами и без, сообщества активные и документация [Перевод руководства по созданию приложения](http://ru.discovermeteor.com/)